schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization .net Extract base64-encoded binary data in php
I have some data sererialized in c# .net application using
c# .net deserialize xml binary
public static object DeSerializeXmlBinary(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (XmlDictionaryReader rdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(bytes, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
        {
            NetDataContractSerializer serializer; 
            serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
            serializer.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
            return serializer.ReadObject(rdr);
        }
    }

how can i deserialize the same in PHP
Update 1
string to be deserialized: https://pastebin.com/FrUNsm9H
parse the string to php function and serialize it.
after parsing the above serialized sting, to base 64 the response will be
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAEmASEDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD3ZmOe3QdqTcfQfkKG6/gP5UlAC7j6D8hRuPoPyFJRQAu4+g/IUbj6D8hSUUALuPoPyFG4+g/IUlFAC7j6D8hRuPoPyFFFABuPoPyFLuPoPyFJRQAu4+g/IUbj6D8hSUUALuPoPyFG4+g/IUlFAC7j6D8hRuPoPyFJRQAu4+g/IUbj6D8hSUUALuPoPyFG4+g/IUlFAC7j6D8hRuPoPyFJRQAu4+g/IUbj6D8hSUUALuPoPyFG4+g/IUlFAC7j6D8hRuPoPyFJRQAu4+g/IUbj6D8hSUUALuPoPyFG4+g/IUlFAC7j6D8hTlY7h06+lMpV++v1oAf5x9KKiooAVuv4D+VJSt1/AfypKACiiigAoopaACiiigAooooAKKKKACiikzTAWioLq9trKIy3M8cSDu7AVwms/FrRdPkKWgN4w4JTpQB6F+FMMqhtuR9a8F1z41alcArp4+ykdwMmudk+KfiSRQX1B2HuoFAj6ceZI03uwC+tZ58QaYsmxr63VvRnAr5luPHuv3ow125X0BNUm1m9mX982c9z1oHZn1mt3E6b1kQpjIYNxUMt98n7go744BOM18rWusalZHda6lcR+28kfkanbxPrfmiU6nKXA7GkFmfRE/jS0068W11aNrR2+65+6fxrctNSs7+LzLa4ikX1Vs184WPjaa8i+w61Gt9A3Hz/AH196iuhdaFqFteaPqE0VvI/7obuA3pQFj6b8zDYP507OBkn3rzzwn48/tZotM1gLFeOCI5V4VzXUQ6lNZ6gLHUBhJTiCTsx9KANwHIz69KWo4iCn0ODUlABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABSr99frSUq/fX60ANooooAVuv4D+VJSt1/AfypKACiiloAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKK5zxd4ttPCemNcXDB53GIYQeWP+FAG1e3tvp9u1xdTxwxLyWc4ryPxZ8YHE7W3h4AoODOw4P0rzrxJ4y1LxFO0uoXTLHn5IEPC1zD3Rd87MKO9MdjY1TxBfagzTX95NcOTkqWO38qwpbt5FKhtoPRRVZrhpJCqZbP5VNK6WUQOAZiOg7UCQxvMVVO4D2oE5X5i2faqpmkZt7Hr1p5i3fODnNAyz9tl/hAVaPt+Ocbz6VRZihx+VIeG3dvSiwrl/7asnDZjqJ5JEbdvJ9CKqH5juHSnhjjGeKGh3LUd0+7exHTr61uWetslmbacebbOMBT1jbsa5ntinxthtvZqQHpFlqTGxWKaVRLCcK6+nUHP1r1Pw54gXxP4OkjvDtv7E/Mx68dD+VfO8F4R5bbiCPlrtvB2tNaSXFupJN0PL/+vQFj6G0m7F5a29yWGJ4VYfhwa1cg5HpXLeHCyaVpccgwyxlcZ7ZrqFwc4GKBC0UUUAFFFFABRRRQAUq/fX60lKv31+tADaKKKAFbr+A/lSUrdfwH8qSgApaSigBaKKKACiiigApCeelLSNjHv2oAyvEWu2/h/Rp7+c/cX5V/vHsK+ZvEPiW98RXz3t/Jk5Plp2UelehfGXxFu1CHQoZAQi+bKPr0FeM3k652jpTAgeRQ7N99z27CoGZypMmR6AUF9v3Rz602JHkmBduPSgZag2Rx+awxjtVGUtLIWXv61euIzNIqJ93vVuDRt2No5pN2KUGzECOmd3Q05N65Azg11kPhyV1yYz+VTf8ACNsByoFZuqaKgzjCjE5Iye1IQTxiuw/4Rxz0U/lVa60B4k3YP5VSqIHSaOX2t0xgetA64rRltyEK45qqIDu6VSdzJqxGFJpVUlsVKU28VNGoAJPemIhz8ygdRXQeHllfVLfbuyDWCsfmSmup8PTpYXKyY3uo+Qe9Io9/0C583U7S0TJ8mHJ59a7YfTGOted/D5JZnmv2ORLwXPc98V6EvQHPNBA7NGaKKAFopKWgAooooAKVfvr9aSlX76/WgBtFFFACt1/AfypKVuv4D+VJQAUUUUAFFJRQAtFJRQAtMmkWGGSVuiIWP4U6oL0RtZTrK2IzG276YoA+UvFGpnUtc1HUZPmklmZVz2QdK5B33ZrpPExhS9uhBzCJCEI+tct3x60xk6rux7VZiQg4AyWqKAZYD1rc0mwa51KKPGQc0pySRdODkyxYac7FVCDn2ruNH8OxlVZo+am0/R1hdRszj1rrbSBY1AHFcNSrc9OnRsVY9Lj8oKEAxUbaHGzcqK3Y1yMYzipBADziua7ZtJ2MRdHhjTHl1BPoNvcRkGPk10wiBGTmkKAdKd5JjvFo8r1bwRtLPD37VxN7o1zZuwZDj6V9AyQblI2jmsHVNDinU7k610QrOO5hOhGSueESWzrycikwNuMj8a9D1bw2iA7Frjbywe3c/ICPpXTGrzHDOi4lKBAp+8Gz7VvaTAkt9DCDl3IGemKxM7TghV47VZ0by/7atkvHdUZvlK9TWu5jsfVfh3T4rTSLaKMYCqM89TW3jHFZOgW8dtpNtHEzFNgILda1u9BDFpabS0ALRRRQAtFJS0AFKn3l+tJTkHzD60ANopcUUAI3X8B/KkpW6/gP5U2gBaKSigAopKKAFopKTNADqzPEMkUXh2/knOI1hbJ9K0M1wvxYv5rPwXIkKk+fIsbEelCA+btXbzJPk+6XYgetZBUh8YrUlaNz0yQfyqO3g86cDHfFDdirXdizomnPd3Cnadua7vRtNW21mLjsaseHNIS2gVmTrzXS/YFZg6rhww5rkqTdz06VJRVy1awlpGIHQ1qLgEYplna7YuvJq0kNcu51JksZAHFTK46U2OHipPK44oSJuIxCrUIc5xU6xMetPW2+bNDiwukQ49eKjkhVx1q48WBVd/lp201J66GLf2ELKcrXn3iLTRHG7IuK9RnAfg1yXiOz3277RmrpysyakeaJ5BNGJGPHzLVONj9vhBGfmHQ961byNoZXGOtVbK3Es8UAC+YXyrHivQg9LnlSWp9U+DY54/DNn57FiUyMnOB2roc81h+Fbee08NWMNwytIsY5U5BFbWaZmPzRmmjpS0AOpaSigBaWkpaACnJ94fWm05fvD60AJkUUlFACN1/AfypKVuv4D+VNzQAtJRmkJoAM0maSkoAcTxSZpD0puaAH1znjixTUPCl7E44VC4b0IroM1FcwJcwPHIu5SpGPWgD48ngkgaTeMMDjHetXwtZ/bL+NSNwB5rQ8bWH2DxBeQbe+Vz6Vp/DeyEk07lelRUdkb0VeZ2qwJZwgucKBwKqjWohNt34XPWrmq2skx2fw1mJ4dknB2Nt9zXLp1O+76G9DrlmpUSXCrWrBqFpKN0c8b+2a5SPwPM3zzznd2wKbL4Tnt23q7gjuDgUpcgJzO4ivImJAK/gasCRSOtcVZpNaMdxY56mtyC6aRRjPFZOS6G6i3ubXmAck1HJqUMIJZ1GPWsyadvLI5rHlgkuJCScg8YzTU11CUHbQ0rzxfp8RKvIfqorMn8V21xxDIRx1xTofDEE7h5U4PUYq2PBOn4LbSD14NaqUTmkpXMVNecThWYspPUmtiWNL21JBDAj0ps3h+GJMQxgY9atada+UNpOaTatoNX6njeu232fVXibv0qfwdo66n4nt7VtpIO8g98GtLx5bLDr6+hXNTfDBYn8XxFiRJjKn+lddJ3RwVVaVj6Et4Vgt44lACqoAA7VLR049KKsxFpRSUooAdSim04UALS0lLQAU5fvD602nL94fWgBtFFFACN1/AfypppzdfwH8qjoAWkPWimmgBaaetLSGgBKKTvS0ANoB+cClpk5227v/AHRmk3YLN7Hz78Uk/wCKvmOBtI6+9afwyh/0O6kxzuxWJ45uWvdZ83YdoJBPvXUfDmP/AIk87+r1lUldHZTg4T1OmkRJQQ3Udqrz6pZaVFmeQKo6g9avSRgxnHDdjXL3fhZtSvRcTTtuU5APIrkT11OxrTQkuvihpFozQGCdyvVhj+tX7Dxxp+pQhjBIkJOA7DPNc/q/gCDVphLM6hgMEp8tb2n6IlppKaZGsf2YdePm+ua0k4W0Iip31NJ0il+ZQNrcgirVlZoPxrOjQWsSW0ZJVT361q2mVUE1zdTrWwXFoBxVPy47ZsvjbjJJ7VqTEsM1QuYBdW5iYkA+neiyvqTd2Me/8cWmloCYJZgTgFBgZ/GqNn8VNOunWI2k6FujHB/lVzWdB/tXSTp8oUL/AAui4K1keHvAUek+YwdJJGBG6QZ/IV1JwSOWSqOWh1lnrFpqcZFvLn2NXIEUN0xXN2nhKLTpvNgmkDE5IzxXSQIUjw/J9ayvqa2ly6nmnxNhCalayD+NSKy/h1M8fimGRU34O0j0HrXR/E6ESDT5QP4iKyPDWl3Wj3UN6GK5YFvcGuqE0kcc6TqVHY+huw5zxRUVvJ5ttFJ/eUGpa2TurnG1Z2FpRSCnCmIKcKKKAFpaKKACnL94fWm05fvD60ANooooARuv4D+VR1I3X8B/Ko6ACmmnU00AJRRRQAmKWiigBKinIWCQn+4eKlpkgVo3QjllIpSWhUfiR474n0uCfRZ327ZBIWBq14BiMOgOOp8yk8QhvtzWchwrZxWh4Vgay02SAjPz5/CuS56s4aqRsAZbnvU6QqRzzUKEdfersQBFZ2LWiGfZVY5CgU2S3AjI6fSroJQdKrXD4jak4qw022ZQVBLgjGKuqVwAKyFl8y4IBzzWpEhYY5zWVtTboWd4244qMIu8HrSGFsZ5xUDy+TIuTxTtrqQ/I0zApXOOvakEI3Z2D8qfFJuQEcipVbJwOorXlTMXoQvEu37oqttVcjHXoKvSfdqqwGaVtRdLnHePbcNY2GR9yYGr0kENzpUMUAG5dp96teI7JbyGIsflQ7qpeF4WvdTZVJMaEA1fWxdKPKnNno1gpTT7dW6hBmrFNUAKFHQcU6u2Ksjx5u8mxRThTRThTJFpRSUooAdRSCloAKcv3h9aSlX7w+tADaKKKAEbr+A/lUdSN1/AfypuKAG0lONJQA2m5pSabQAZozRSUALmjgg5pKTGTQB574o0wXV3IUOJUbK+9Gjh4FZXUiQAZrf8RWpEqTqvsaz4jlhjrjnArhkmmeymp0VboOJ+brVyHJXiqQ5Yk1atnqL6gndF4fd5rF1e5bIjQcHgmtjcCtZN/bNMCUPI7U3sXBalaIWtrD5k7qoAyWJwKfba1ay5McivjgYPFYOo6bcajF9mu4T9nzzg8miLRlso0S1Xy06BTUqxry3OmbV4ljILKijqScCmK9vexMySK2ehU5rn7rQlu7YxXLM4P8KmnaPpdxpyiC2iKwA92pNC5bHRaVK+4xv0U8VtKAGJrPtLdY8E/e9Kvn7tXFmFR6kUrcGq2QWwc0+Z85Apq8MMDOetO+pN7Iq3kRnRowcAjFWfC2nJaSP5Q+p96ry7hMcEH0FdBpELW9sGdcM5yRVwi3K5FSpy0eU0ee9FHeiuw8sUU4U0U4UAOpaSloABTu9NFO70AHalX7w+tJ2pV+8PrQA2iiigBG6/gP5U2nN1/AfyppoAQ00mnUxqAGGkpTSUAFFFFABR3oooC5DcWyXUTRv0PT2rEbQGt5GmSfKr/DiuhHWkZdyMD3qJU1uaRqSi7HJSDDH3psJKtip5lxK4x0NQHjmuOSsz0ou6LXmfLUbEg4POajL/AC9aqTX0ULfvHxj3qNzVFmVA4wTUWwBeR06E1lz65G77YWAx1JqtLqhMisJh1x9afKbRTN9F3gnrirMMYByOPrXNPqDCQDzguewNSprMkL4YiSP69KErDlFpHVrtBwOKkEgZTg9Kw7fWLecDy3yx7elasGOG9aZytDZBjnFEG4EkjOelTSkUtsA8yL6mqhuZzlZGpBp9uuH8sGQjOTVzt057Ui9ce1LXbBJHmzk2xR0opBS9qZIopwpopwoAdS0lLQACnd6aKd3oAO1Kv3h9aTtSr94fWgBtFFFACN1/AfyptObr+A/lTaAENManmmsKAI6KKKACiloxQA2iiigAoPIxSgUuOc0Ac5qyNDdFscMBWdnc3NdLq9uZ7YyAfNGM8VyxbuvfrXJVjqd9Cd42JCBmsLVtKiu/vM6t7NWpJLtFRM+7qBWF7HbT2Ofi0eGIYIdiP7zdatQ2VmvVFLehPStkKGTBwaYbWFuqAE96Oc2U7FNbO2IyyITSGxhkY/uwFI7VdiskV+WzV6FVHYD6UcwSqXM6w0iC3bzFXB963YpBGmBVWViDhaZGzE80r3MKmxe8wGrenR77xW/u1lksBlcE10GlQGOLzW6sOK3pLU468rRsaHRgaWkPNFdaOBu4tL2pBS9qYCinjpTBThQAtOptOoABS0gpaACnL94fWm05fvD60ANooooARuv4D+VNpzdfwH8qbQAhpDSmkoAYRSU+m4oASilxRigBMUYpaKACiilFAAw3KFxwetcVqUAstReEcK3zD6V2/pXJ+KYf9Ljl9VxWVVe7c6MO7SsZAQO3NIbVieOlQR3PzbG496vRzKeK4tz0k7aCw27dMZqz9mAXLdaQShBx3qRLhcfPQkg5yMQo/HcdcVKLcKMLR9oiRt20c8VJ56k8U2kh89yJocdetQldjc1NLOtZs15uJjj+YmloJu5YD4ZufpXX2YIs4s/3a4uPOBnr3rtbX/j0i/3a6KDucWKRNRRRXScVhRTu1NFOpgKKUUg6UtADqWkpaAFooooAKcv3h9abTl+8PrQA2iiigBG6/gP5U2nN1/AfyptACGkpTSUAJSUtJQAUlLSUAFFFHNABThSYPalHQk8AUAKAd2TjbXPeLEzFAwHAzk1LqXi3R9NlMElx5twOPKi5P/1qxtT13+1bcKIWiXOQrHJrKrJctjejGXMmYrKuetMDSR8gnFS7A1IQehrgR6jV0MbUGGM8Y9aT+1E/icZ+tDQRycMtRNokUvIq7kuJI2qRbcM6/hTodXXGFy30qKHQE3cqce9akOlwW65VAGpOQKJWaSe5HdFPr1p9vb+Wc559astGOvenrHgZNZNu5aWgi/eGa7O1ObSL/drjsZPHatyLXLa1t1E4dVUYyBmunDO25x4qLext0VBa3tteR74JlcHoAean5x059K7Vrsee9NxRS9qSlpgOFKKaKUGgB9LTc04GgApaSloAKVfvr9aSlX76/WgBtFFFAA3X8B/Km05uv4D+VNoAQ0lONNPWgBKSlpM0AFJSFsUyS4hiGWYD6U7ASUjMqrlmCj1zWZPq6oCIFyfU1lyTy3LfvZD6gelFgZrXGtQW+Vjy7ds9Kw9R1i6+xSyM+3jAVaZIMSoC3BzVW/gMloy++aHpG5UdZWZg6ZpMNoGumUyXUzF5JH569qvtjdVtI8wqfaoWjry5SbZ60IpIatTeXkdKgUbWq9EcipuaFUw8/SrER2YyKkKc804bcYp3AsLJEUzmoWbceKaIx/eqVVUD1pCI9ual2fLUgA7CkbrRYLlcjBpOGO1uh9qfjmkIyaFJrYXKnuUjbS2E4vbBzGwPzx5+VhXUW+pSuqSHDIy8+1ZGw+W30qSxYizX6kGuzDTbVmcOKppO6OkhuklQFT1qwBxurnYdyHOeM8Vow3+3Cv8AdrqscZpilqvHOknQip8Fh97IoaAcKcKbkYxRmkA+lpuaWgBaVfvr9abSr99frQAlFJRQArdfwH8qZmnOefwH8qZQAZpO9LUM0yQpuY/QU7ASF1UEntVCfU4kyFG4iqc1y8rEhsL6CqxJ9KaQiw+pTSjao2j1FU5CWOWJJp7SER8ihdrjJ6VVgIWCilChhyKcUDNxTym0cUWGV50DbDjocGmuu5GUdganYfuuevWlVcRlvWla6sHW5mwIXh2jqnBqOZGRsYq1kW13/wBM36mpZY97ZArzKkbSZ6tKV4oyzEcZqSFtpxV0xDFVJIirZArKzRsncsZOOlG3PamwuGGD2qdVz0oGMENSqoUYxQE96dg07EgTgdKgLktUrcCogpJyBSGgwSadsAGTUix+tTLGCKdhMryt5UWT3H86swReXCu4ds1VVReXYiBzDF8xb3rQJXyyAc44ruoQsrnn4qd3YYCGzg4Hak2kg8GnDIjXjBxzQSBjbnNdJyApZf4j9BViK+aM8tn2NV8A8kYPrRsB7fjQ0BqR6irnBGKuK6sAVYGuexs/i609HlXoSv40rAdFzmlyRWTbX8inZIPxrSRgy7lOQaTQyTNPQ/Ov1qLpTk/1i/UUgCim0UAK55/AfyphNK3UfQfyqGaURxlm4x096aAbc3KQR/MeT0FZE8rSHcWyaSaZp33P26VFkD6VSQBmnAjujH3pEYckrwfek6ngVSQiTcvHyUOA3KjApAcdad94YoAbsUd6Dg9CDSbR1zk+lKF9TtPpQAwgE44pnKN833alKkcjmkb94MECgZBNEJk2gcH+L0qvBI6jyHH3eh9atfvEynamvFuGSQCO9Y1aXMtDajW5HqRk0jKGFPUbuGXFSiCuCUGnZnpRnFq5UEYU8d6sxpxUywL3FPEYHSp5S+ZEfl0FKlxRsJNFiblcx5GKbs21b8o9qGjXHNHK2w50kUmyKhdpZBsj4J7+lW3Uvwq/KOpoReCAAAO9dFOg73Zz1MRFIZBF5KeWBwep9TUy84B+6KVIzKeuAO9TlYxFuQDcOp9a7krKyPObbd2REtuxkY7UFTtycU/AbB2gE+9L5fGSwxRYQ3Hy1HhqkOR0INM3EHtQA0g5GaczYpwbcR0NMIJk6cUASBjjI6VLBdsjZGdtVz8xxTiAq4pDNyKdZFGOc1Mh/eL9RWBbzGJuCfpWvbTq5X5ucjipaAmyKKj3n0FFIB7dM+w/lWJf3QeTZuyo9K0ryXy4uDzgfyrFmO0biuTVRQCLlsnsO/pUcmR0Gc96eDuTAOAecetQh2eUK7fKpyBV2ETnasajHNPAwKgXOWc9M8VYD5jxtz9aADK8Zo5+lMbIwdv5GlWPdyN30oATac5U5NLy3LHJHpSn0PFIM5wKQAASPakEfOQTTzuUUgJ96AGuF7k1X3ASY5Iq0VL9F/GgjYuGX9KewrEJYMOvNLHIwOGH0FHlrnNNyoPz5z2FTKCZcZyiWhMmPmUin74ycZqoXbb8hB+tMZjvG5sGsnQubxxDRd3LnG4ZpryKn8QqoVO7K9e9DbOMct3FSsPYp4m5YaZsfIPxqP5zyzAn0FRtLyO3sKdGDnLIQexzWsaaRlKq2LvK8AH3FSxKxzlcA1KkS43dT60jbmYDHTvWmljJ3GkMnA+7TjtGArZz2Ip5iOASP1phIIOSBj0pCGcjqB160vORnG2kOMDB3U5scZ49hQAv+7gUFcqTgZoG2kIGfvgg9qAGhHUF9oAHvTgxI34z7UjEcqDgd6YuMYUmgBWbnIB4p4Zc5IJpA4WJuxqFHcj7wI+lOwFhtvVeCKfCxjkVgec1ENpHQ59alXqv1pNDH/bnoqtiipAm1WcC6C8/ImentWfu/wBGMm9tx9qKKuJIsJARCWJ/CkTafNfJyDjpRRVASIQwG49ParCBOTk/lRRSAj2K2fmP5UpIAxuP5UUUhisF4bJ/Kmoqksd7D6CiigBw2Zxlj+FK2F6MfyoooAdGQwPzMD64pB82UZ2I+lFFAEZjUnarsPfFTAR7cPlse1FFAFVooWbIBGPQU37PHJyHcY9aKKAHpbIyZ86UEelOW3hiO4M5z1zRRQBIfKi+6vJ7laWGWNjkg/lRRQBLKygZBYfhUQlBI5PHtRRQBO5V1ByfyqMhCcjOfpRRQA4snQf+g0046g4P+7RRSAYrr5hzkn6UriPHf8BRRTASNFycsTnplaaxAfax4HoKKKAHxuhTBB/Ko9qCTAJ59qKKAHxsu4rk4+lSbUZOp4I7UUUARbRRRRQB/9k=

Update 2
String in DB
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

What i have found so far

The string is first i decode from base64 base64_decode()
Then i deflate the string gzinflate()
After which the string is parsed, this is where i have reached.

step 1 & 2 i have confirmed in the c# code base and output are expected.
update 3
parsing code in c#
 ms = new MemoryStream(((System.Byte[])DecompressData(System.Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToString(__DBSTRING__)))));
 byte[] byteArr = ms.ToArray();
___OUTPUT___= Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr);


private static object DecompressData(byte[] inb)
    {
        byte[] outb;
        using (MemoryStream istream = new MemoryStream(inb))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ostream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream sr =
                    new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(istream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    sr.CopyTo(ostream);
                } outb = ostream.ToArray();
            }
        } return DeSerializeXmlBinary(outb);
    }

the xml part is what i don't understand why?

What is "the same"? Can you share a sample string that you want to deserialize?

"the NetDataContractSerializer includes CLR type information in the serialized XML, whereas the DataContractSerializer does not. Therefore, the NetDataContractSerializer can be used only if both the serializing and deserializing ends share the same CLR types." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.8.1 . So I wonder if this is really the best format to share between languages, since it serializes .NET-specific information. I think DataContractSerializer is more designed for your purpose.

ok, adding an update

And unless you have some specific reason for doing it like this at all, have you considered using JSON instead for your data interchange instead of a .NET-specific XML format? PHP already has built-in functionality to deserialise JSON, and .NET can easily serialize to JSON too. That would almost certainly be a lot less work than writing a deserializer in PHP for the XML data.

Not to mention that the XML is encoded in an MS-specific binary format...

The issue I have is the data is already in a system database made with C#.net 3 or something of that error, I have to read the data and pass to php.

PS: this is an image encode in db for clients

Storing language-specific serialized data in a database is really a bad idea. Consider writing some C# code to convert the data to an interoperable format.

Whatever you mean by "image encode": please share what that string should be deserialized to, and what you've tried to achieve that

the last output is a data:image/png;base64,

If it's an image, then how on earth is XML involved? My organisation doesn't allow access to pastebin so I can't check what you've posted there. As per [ask] please provide a [mre] of your issue within your question. Thanks.

If you know that this is a raw image, what's missing to take the next steps? Which format do you want to deserialize it to?

"how on earth is XML involved" The serializer uses (binary) XML format to encode objects (see here).

Does the serialized data always encode a byte[] array?

@Olivier I have added update 3 above, the short answer is yes. long answer: c#  code to parse the data uses byte code and in PHP we use stings, when i convert the string to byte array in step 2 above, I get the same results

@Olivier sure, but if the objective is to encode an image as base64, I'm struggling to see how  serializing to binary XML would be a useful step for that! But I guess we are where we are, in terms of this existing code.

@ADyson Of course, it's crazy, not to mention the compression step (which is useless for images since they are already compressed).

"the last output is a data:image/png;base64" Acrually, the image given in the question is a JPEG, not a PNG.

After taking a look at the .NET XML binary format specification,
here is a simple way to extract data from a serialized byte[] array:
function extractData($ser)
{
    $pos = 154;
    if($ser[$pos] != "\xA0")
        throw new Exception('Bytes16Text record not found');
    $a = unpack('vlen', substr($ser, $pos+1, 2));
    $len = $a['len'];
    $data = substr($ser, $pos+3, $len);

    $pos += 3 + $len;
    if($ser[$pos] != "\x9F")
        throw new Exception('Bytes8TextWithEndElement record not found');
    $a = unpack('Clen', substr($ser, $pos+1, 1));
    $len = $a['len'];
    $data .= substr($ser, $pos+2, $len);

    return $data;
}

$db = file_get_contents('db.txt');
$ser = gzinflate(base64_decode($db));
$image = extractData($ser);
file_put_contents('image.jpg', $image);

Note: this code will only work for arrays smaller than 64KB. You will need to adapt it in case you have larger arrays.

hey am getting alot of Bytes16Text record not found while extracting the data

@MureithiMaina As I said, the code only works for arrays smaller than 64KB. You may have bigger ones. It's time for you to read the specifications I linked, use a hex editor to inspect the data, and fix the code.
